# Add a summary information to WiX generated MSI

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, wix3

How to add (or change a default values) a summary page information to a WiX-generated MSI file?

Summary page is the tab page which is visible if you right click on the MSI file in the Windows Explorer and includes following text fields:

Title,
Subject,
Author,
Category,
Keywords,
Comments

[alt text http://img151.imagevenue.com/img.php?image=13824_msi_summary_122_495lo.jpg](http://img151.imagevenue.com/img.php?image=13824_msi_summary_122_495lo.jpg)

Answer (score 10):

Further to @Stefan answer, here's a mapping of Wix items to msi details properties. have not found a way to set "category" property at all.
[image]

Comment: What about "Authors"?

Comment: Manufacturer field of Product

Answer (score 9):

That information is set in the `<Package>` element, for example:

```
<Wix xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2003/01/wi'>
  <Product
  UpgradeCode="SOMEGUID-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"  
  Name='MyApp' 
  Id='????????-????-????-????-????????????'
  Language='1033' 
  Codepage='1252' 
  Version='1.0.0' 
  Manufacturer='MyCompany'>
    <Package
    Id="*"
    Keywords="keyword1, keyword2, keyword3"
    Description="summary of application"
    Comments="some comments"
    Manufacturer="mycompany"
    InstallerVersion="300"
    Languages="1033"
    Compressed="yes"
    SummaryCodepage="1252"/>
```

Comment: And where can I set the Title?
Thanks!

Comment: You can try setting the title with the Msiinfo.exe utility. However, please note that in the example below MS recommends that the Title should be "Installation Database". At the top of the page, it says that invalid summary information could cause MSI validation failure. YMMV.


Source: An Installation Example - Adding Summary Information
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367533(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Another way to set the summary info of an MSI is by using [Msiinfo.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370310.aspx) utility. We use this in our build system to set some of the values that could not be set while generating the MSI file (in a post build step).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to set the information *after* creating the MSI you can also edit the summary information using [Orca](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370557%28VS.85%29.aspx) from the Windows SDK. To install it, first install the Windows SDK then install Orca from the MSI file at C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Bin\orca.msi .  Set the information through *View -> Summary Information...* .