# Set title in WIX MSI description

Tags: wix, windows-installer

[image]

How do I change the text "Installation Database" in Title properties in WIX ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Title` property of the Summary Information stream cannot be set by pure WiX facilities. That is discussed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621470/add-a-summary-information-to-wix-generated-msi).

Note that by default the `Title` property holds the information about the type of the installation package: "Installation Database" (MSI), "Transform" (MST) or "Patch" (MSP). It is still possible to modify this property with the [Msiinfo.exe utility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370310.aspx). [Microsoft recommends](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372083.aspx) keeping predefined phrases for different types of packages in.

Answer (score 0):

I found this: http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/How-to-set-Title-in-Summary-Information-Stream-td709628.html

Alexander Schevchu says:
"If you have Platform SDK installed (specifically, Windows Installer SDK) (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=0BAF2B35-C656-4969-ACE8-E4C0C0716ADB&displaylang=en), in the Bin folder there is MsiInfo.exe file.  This tool allows setting Summary Info properties. To set the Title property: 
msiinfo MyMsi.msi /T "My personal Title" "

Tried. Works.